# rails, adding file in app/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new file in app/views/students called courses.html.erb

Then I try to reference it at app/views/students/show.html.erb:

<%= link_to 'courses', courses_student_path(@student) %>

However I am getting

undefined method `courses_student_path' for #<#:0x1052d1648>

What step did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you never link to views. It is always some action in some controller which in turn renders that view. In this case your action is `courses` in `students` controller and you need to create a route for it.

Assuming you already had `:students` resource defined in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :students do
  get 'courses', :on => :member
end
```

This will give you urls like `students/1/courses` and route helpers `courses_student_path` and `courses_student_url`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: You can also do 'rake routes' to see a list of your current routes. Really helps me as a noob to rails